# If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ then $|f(\mathbb{N})|\leq\aleph_0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am stuck at this problem for long time:

---

Prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is some real-valued function, Then $|f(\mathbb{N})|\leq\aleph_0$.

In other words, prove that there exists a one-to-one function from $f(\mathbb{N})=\{f(n)|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

---

If $f(\mathbb{N})$ is finite then it is clear that $|f(\mathbb{N})|\leq\aleph_0$,
But if $f(\mathbb{N})$ is infinite then I got stuck.

Thanks for any hint/help.

Comment: To $y \in f({\mathbb N})$ assign the least $n\in{\mathbb N}$ such that $f(n) = y$.

Comment: Your "in other words" interpretation is not true.

Comment: @mvw why not true? By definition $|A|\leq|B|$ if and only if there exists a one-to-one function from $A$ to $B$ (Comparing sets in this article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\vert S \vert \le \aleph_0$ is equivalent to, by definition, the existence of a function with $f(\mathbb{N}) = S$.

Comment: *cough* $|S|=0$ *cough*

Comment: My function doesn't have to be from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, it can be any function.  So $f = \emptyset$ and $f(\mathbb{N}) = \emptyset$ demonstrates that $0 \le \aleph_0$.

Comment: There is absolutely no function from a nonempty set to the empty set. If you can prove otherwise, congratulations, you proved first order logic is inconsistent.

Comment: I think this is just an issue of semantics?  By "$f(\mathbb{N})$" I mean $\{y \vert \exists x: x \in \mathbb{N} \land (x,y) \in f\}$.  So $f(X) = \emptyset$ just means $X$ and the domain of $f$ are disjoint.  How else should I understand the notation?

Comment: No, try again to parse this definition with the image being empty.

Comment: I'm still not following you.  The image of the empty function restricted to $\mathbb{N}$ is empty, so according to my definition, $0 \le \aleph_0$.

Comment: What is the domain of the empty function? Can that domain be anything *but* the empty set? Is $\Bbb N$ empty?

Comment: The domain of the empty function is the empty set.  $\mathbb{N}$ isn't empty.  But if $f = \emptyset$ then what's wrong with writing $f(\mathbb{N}) = \emptyset$?  What could that possibly mean other than what I wrote in my second comment?

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. Yes, under your interpretation, this is correct. Generally, however, one usually takes $f(X)$ to mean that $X$ is a subset of the domain of $f$. (Hence my insistence.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55767/discussion-between-dan-brumleve-and-asaf-karagila).